# Android Dual Sim Reject incoming Call

Tags: android

Please help our android application calls Reject incoming calls in application, code works fine for single SIM android , in dual SIM getting issue.

Following is my code :

BroadcastReceiver

```
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mainPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("mainPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String rejectMode = mainPrefs.getString("mode", "not retrieved");

    if (rejectMode.equals("enable")) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                RejectcallHandler mDbAdapter = new RejectcallHandler(context);
                mDbAdapter.open();
                Cursor cursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAllRejectList();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                        String rejectNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RejectcallHandler.COLUMN_RCNUMBER));
                        if (incomingNumber.startsWith(rejectNumber)) {
                            rejectCall(context, intent);
                            //showNotification(context, incomingNumber);

                            String value = mainPrefs.getString("show_notification", "notify_enable");

                            if (value.equals("notify_enable")) {
                                showNotification(context, incomingNumber);
                            }
                        }
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
                mDbAdapter.close();
            }
        }
    } else if (rejectMode.equals("disable")) {

    }
}
```

Here my android manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```